# Node Js App gives EADDRNOTAVAlL Error after 2 hours worked

Tags: node.js, sql-server, docker, docker-compose, axios

I have an app that consumes data from Kafka and sends it to a container named DB. After the program starts it maybe works 2 hours and then its gives on the consumer Axios catch:

> Api error :connect:EADDRNOTAVAL:3002 (Thats the port from DB container )

### Consumer Side Code

```
import { Kafka } from "kafkajs";
import axios from "axios";
// Paketlerin nereden geldiğinin bilgisi
const clientId = "my-app";

// Cluster Hangi Porta Yollayacak
const brokers = ["kafka:9092"];

// Gonderilen Topic
const topic = ["Topic2", "Topic3"];
const kafka = new Kafka({ clientId, brokers });
const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: clientId });

let buffer = [];

export const consume = async () => {
  await consumer.connect();
  await consumer.subscribe({ topics: ["Topic2", "Topic3"] });

  await consumer.run({
    autoCommitInterval: 500,
    eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
      const pkg = JSON.parse(message.value);
      if (buffer.length < 500) {
        buffer.push(pkg);
      }
    },
  });
};

setInterval(async () => {
  const data = JSON.stringify(buffer);

  buffer = [];
  if (!data.length > 0) {
    console.log("İşlenecek veri olmadıgı için veri işleme alınmadı ");
  } else {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://db:3002/handle_data", data, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      data = [];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`API error:${error}`);
    }
  }
}, 200);
```

### DB SIDE CODE

The index.js file; runs on port **3002**

```
  import { handle_data } from "./handle_data.js";
  import express from "express";
  //import sql from "mssql";
  import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
  //const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
  import cors from "cors";

  const app = express();
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json({ limit: "100mb" }));

  app.post("/handle_data", handle_data);
  app.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log("DB SİDE İS ALLİVE ");
  });
```

#### The Function

```
import sql from "mssql";

export const handle_data = (req, res) => {
  const dataArray = req.body;

  if (dataArray.length > 0) {
    bulkInsert(req.body);
  } else {
    console.log(
      "Eklenecek Konum Verisi Olmadıgı İçin ekleme işlemi yapılamadı "
    );
  }
};
async function bulkInsert(data) {
  const config = {
    server: "A",
    database: "A",
    port: 1433,
    user: "A",
    password: "A",
    options: {
      trustServerCertificate: true,
      encrypt: false,
    },
  };

  try {
    await sql.connect(config);

    const table = new sql.Table("tblLocations");
    table.create = false;
    table.columns.add("TaskId", sql.BigInt);
    table.columns.add("DoorNumber", sql.NVarChar(10));
    table.columns.add("Latitude", sql.Float);
    table.columns.add("Longitude", sql.Float);
    table.columns.add("EmbeddedTime", sql.DateTime);
    table.columns.add("HatKodu", sql.NVarChar(10));
    table.columns.add("GuzergahKodu", sql.NVarChar(50));

    data.forEach((location) => {
      table.rows.add(
        location.taskId,
        location.doorNumber,
        location.Latitude,
        location.longitude,
        location.embeddedTime,
        location.hatKodu,
        location.routeCode
      );
    });

    const request = new sql.Request();
    await request.bulk(table);

    console.log(` ${data.length} Adet Veri Veritabanına Eklendi ...`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Data uzunlugu :::::::::::::::::   ${data.length}`);
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
  }
}
```

EDIT:

When the consumer side starts to give an error the db side gives nothing on the logs or errors.

Host: Linux Centos 8

Comment: Have you checked the container DB logs? Which docker host do you have Linux/Windows? What command do you issue to run the container db?

Comment: Yes when the consumer side starts to give a error the db side gives nothing on the logs or errors ı use centos 8 linux the app works 2 hours and then its starts to give this error

Comment: AFTER the error you can ping the container? If you restart the client can you start again or raise an error? The mssql database is internal to the container or is it another container? Can you reach the mssql after the error? After the error have you tried with posman or curl to execute the POST to http://db:3002/handle_data to see if the error persists? You must isolate the problem from the server or the client. If the problem is on the mssql part, also try to change the mssql [connection to pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connections-1)

Comment: when the db container is down when ı restart it manually it starts to work for 2 hours again. but two containers are binded and dont know how to access the db container bcs its receiving only request from the consumer container @Max